# наложение фона на контент

Tags: css

Собственно хотел реализовать своего рода "модальное окно" (+ что бы задний фон подключался соответсвующим блоком).С такими стилями сделал блок, но проблема в том что цвет накладывается на все окно браузера, кроме строчных блоков внутри контейнера страницы

css

```
.background_transparent{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right: 0px;
    left:0px;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.6);   
}
```

причем в спецификации к `background` указано что " применяется ко всем элементам"
пример https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/zh10yfma/

Comment: Непонятно к чему не применяется. Примерчик покажите.

Comment: добавил фидл в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!
По клику на любой элемент, который открывает Ваше модальное окно, Вам нужно создать div, который будет реализовывать затемнение, со следующими css свойствами:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; //растянули по всему экрану
z-index: 10;
opacity: 0.75; //добавим прозрачности, чтобы было видно страничку
backgrond-color: #000 //тут цвет фона (тёмный обычно)
```

Т.е. этот div всегда должен быть в структуре (можно конечно и ajax подгружать:)), просто по-дефолту ему display: none. а когда должно появиться модальное окно - этому ДИВУ делаете display: block.

под ним уже делаете блок, именно модального окна

```
margin: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 11; //его z-index должен быть выше, чем у блока, создающего тёмный фон
top: 357px;
left: 406px;
```

В итоге получаем:

```
<div class="Я ДЕЛАЮ ТЁМНЫЙ ФОН"></div>
<div class="Я МОДАЛЬНОЕ ОКНО"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам за труды ) со стилями и самой идеей я в курсе как делать, а вот z-index забыл, и они помогли)

Comment: Рад помочь) Успехов Вам!